# The question about the proof isomorphism between simplicial and singular homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-cohomology

I want mainly to ask the two question while reading **Theorem 2.27** the Hatcher's textbook

> **Theorem 2.27)** The homomorphisms between $H^{\Delta}_n(X,A) \to H_n(X,A) $  are
> isomorphism for all n and all $\Delta$-complex pairs $(X,A)$

one is the question about the proof of isomorphism between simplicial and singular homology group, and next question is the meaning of the proof.

To begin with, let $X^k$ be a $k$-skeleton of $X$. And then, I do not precisely explain why the following

> The simplicial chain group $\Delta_n (X^k, X^{k-1})$ is zero for $n\neq
>  k$, and is free abelian with basis the $k$-simplices of $X$ when $n =
>  k$. ........ (*)

holds. To begin with, *my idea* why (*) holds :

First pick $n=k$. Then, $\Delta_k (X^{k-1})=0$ when considering the dimension. Next, k-skeleton is constructed by the costructed by attaching $n$-cells $\left \{ e_{\alpha}^n \right \} $ which is regarded as basis so that $\Delta_k (X^k)$ is a free abelian group. for convenience, I denoted by $G_{free}$  Hence, $\Delta_k (X^k, X^{k-1})$=$\Delta_k (X^k, X^{k-1})= {\Delta_k (X^k)}/ {\Delta_k (X^{k-1})} $ = $G_{free}/0 \simeq G_{free}  $ . Next, since,

$$  \Delta_n(X^k)\overset{?}{=} \left\{\begin{matrix}
G_{free} ~~~if~~~ n=k \\ 0  ~~~if~~~ n \neq k \end{matrix}\right.$ ...... (♣) $$

Thus,

$$ \Delta_{k-1} (X^k, X^{k-1})= {\Delta_{k-1} (X^k)}/ {\Delta_{k-1}  (X^{k-1})} = 0/{G}_{free} \simeq 0 $$

and,

$$ \Delta_{i} (X^k, X^{k-1})= {\Delta_{i} (X^k)}/ {\Delta_{i-1} (X^{k-1})} = 0/0 \simeq 0 $$ if $ 0 \le i<k-1 $

**Here is the first question** : Is it $(♣)$ right? If $(♣)$ is wrong, I want to ask why (*) holds. Although $(♣)$ is right way, I am not confident why $(♣)$ holds.

Next question comes from the following fact that one can deduce from **Theorem2.27)**. According to the textbook,

> "*We can deduce from this theorem that $H_n(X)$ is finitely generated
> whenever $X$ is a $\Delta$-complex with finitely many $n$ simplices,
> since in this case the simplicial chain group $\Delta_n(X)$ is
> finitely generated, hence also its subgroup of cycles and therefore
> also the latter group’s quotient $H^{\Delta}_n(X)$. If we write
> $H_n(X)$ as the direct sum of cyclic groups, then the number of
> $\mathbb{Z}$ summands is known traditionally as the $n$-th Betti
> number of $X$ , and integers specifying the orders of the finite
> cyclic summands are called torsion coefficients.*"

This description sounds that $H_n(X)$ is actually a finitely generated abelian group due to the **Theorem2.27)**, . I think that $H^{\Delta}_n(X) $ is a finitely generated abelian group because the free abelian group $\Delta_n(X)$ which is homomorphic to finite copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ . In case of singuar homology $C_n(X)$, however, I think that $C_n(X)$ is *just* free abelian group which is homomorphic to $\bigoplus \mathbb{Z} $ ( the number of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ is *countable*(*finite* or *denumerable*)).

Hence, my thought (or second question) is here :
we could not bet that *n*-th singular homology group $H_n(X)$ is **finitely** generated without **Theorem2.27** when we consider a case when the copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable

Is it right thought?

**Edit** : When I think about the first question, my thought is wrong when considering $X^2=T$(Torus).

[image]

Like the above figure, a torus $T$ is obtained from $X^2 = X^1 \coprod_{\alpha} e_{\alpha}/\sim $ (and in fact $X^1$ is homeomorphic to $ S^1 \vee S^1 $ In that case,

$$ \Delta_{1} (X^2, X^{1})= {\Delta_{1} (X^2)}/ {\Delta_{1} (X^{1})} = <a,b,c>/<a,b,c> \simeq 0 $$

From the above, I just *guess*

$$ \Delta_{i} (X^k) \simeq  \Delta_{i} (X^{k-1}) $$..... (◆) if $0\le i<k-1$.

Thus  that $ \Delta_{n} (X^k, X^{k-1}) = 0 $ Here is my thought the relation between $\Delta_n(X^k)$ and  $\Delta_n(X^{k-1})$ and I cannot generalize the case.

**Answer about the question** :  about the question about comparing $\Delta_i(X^k)$ to $\Delta_i(X^{k-1})$, I cannot understand precise intention about the question. Clearly $X^k$ is constructed from $X^{k-1}$ by attaching $e_{\alpha}^n$. If $i=k$, $\Delta_{k}(X^{k})$ is free abelian group generated by $e_{\alpha}^n$ while  $\Delta_k(X^{k-1})=0$ because of the dimension. If $i=k-1$,   $\Delta_{k-1}(X^k)$ is obtained from by mapping $\partial$ : $\Delta_{k}(X^k) \to \Delta_{k-1}(X^k)$, i.e $\Delta_{k-1}(X^k)$ is means the boundary of $X^k$ while $\Delta_{k-1}(X^{k-1})$ is free abelian group generated by $e_{\alpha}^n$. If my guess ,(◆), on the previous **Edit** is right, these two are generated by same basis but I cannot be sure now. That's all I can do I compare them.

Comment: $(\clubsuit)$ is not correct. The $k$-skeleton of $X$ consists of all simplices in $X$ of dimension $k$ and lower (Hatcher p. 128), so $\Delta_n(X^k)$ is zero when $n > k$, not in general otherwise. When $n < k$, what is the relationship between $\Delta_n(X^k)$ and $\Delta_n(X^{k-1})$?

Comment: One comment regarding your second question: in many cases the singular chain group $C_n(X)$ will be free with uncountably many summands. For example $C_0(X)$ has one free summand for every function from a point to $X$.

Comment: (About the second question) Then, am I on the right track when I just correct the singular chain group $C_n(X)$ uncountably many (integer) summands instead of countable copies of integer? / And, about the first question, see the **Edit** on my question.

Comment: Regarding the second question, I don't really understand what track you're on. You seem to be restating what Hatcher says, which I guess is the right track. For the first question, what is the definition of $\Delta_i(X^k)$, and how does that compare to $\Delta_i(X^{k-1})$? And why do you impose the restriction $1<i$?

Comment: In response to your question about impose the restriction, I think that  I should correct the range of $i$, $0 \le i < k-1$. The definition of $\Delta_n(X) $ is just a free abelian group with basis open $n$-simplices $e_{\alpha}^n$ of $X$ like Hatcher's textbook.  I just substitute $X$ into $X^k$(CW $k$-cell complex) [Thus, On the **Edit**,  I consider the torus $T$ which is known as cell-complex by attaching $e_{\alpha}^n$. Hence, $X^2=T $, $\Delta_2(X^2)=<U,L> $ and $X^1=S^1 \vee S^1 $,  $\Delta_1(X^1)=<a,b,c> $ like the image on the above.]

Comment: Because of the limitation of characteristic, I answered The question about comparing $\Delta_{i}(X^k)$ to $\Delta_{i-1}(X^k)$ on the above.

Comment: The key point is that as $\Delta$-complexes, $X^k$ and $X^{k-1}$ have the same $i$-simplices for $0 \leq i \leq k-1$.